# converting time to only hh:mm in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on the query below however I want my results to get displayed with as `hh:mm` format. I am using  `convert(char, mycolumnName, 108)` but my results are still getting displayed as `hh:mm:ss`. I only need `hh:mm`. Is there a way how to get this results in `hh:mm` ? Please advice Thank you in advance!

```
 select distinct 
     clientid, timein , timeout, calculation, 
     convert(char, calculation, 108) as CalculationResult 
 from 
     calculationTable 
 where 
     timein is not null and timeout is not null
```

Output:

```
Clientid   timein     timeout    calculation           CalculationResult
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
0012345    09:00:00   05:00:00   1900-01-01 08:00:00   08:00:00
```

Comment: use `convert(char(5),`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientid,
    timein,
    timeout,
    calculation,
    convert(VARCHAR(5), calculation, 108) AS CalculationResult
FROM calculationTable
WHERE timein IS NOT NULL
AND timeout IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
  distinct clientid, 
  timein, 
  timeout, 
  calculation, 
  convert(varchar(5), calculation, 108) as CalculationResult
```